# Hi there are some who can help me with this ReactJS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I do not return anything but also do not get any errors, what is the solution?

```js
import React from 'react'

function Array() {
    function myConcat() {
    const Villain = ["Harley Quinn", "Brainiac", "Deathstroke"];
    const Hero = ["Superman", "Batman", "Black Canary"];
    const VillainsAndHeroes = Villain.concat(Hero);
        return VillainsAndHeroes;
}
    return (
        <div>
            { myConcat() }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Array
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would recommend NOT calling your component `Array`, which is a built-in object in Javascript, and I think is asking for confusion at least, but more likely trouble: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thank you very much, I want to change it to Arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code [in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-silence-jfqty?file=/src/App.js) and it appears to work.  Compare your code to that.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Array() {
  function myConcat() {
    const Villain = ["Harley Quinn", "Brainiac", "Deathstroke"];
    const Hero = ["Superman", "Batman", "Black Canary"];
    const VillainsAndHeroes = Villain.concat(Hero);
    return VillainsAndHeroes;
  }
  return <div>{myConcat()}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Array />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do the same in another sandbox, you was quicker than me ;)
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64807709-814rg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Haha, many thanks are dying for laughter, common mistake. : 'D